# Class, Interface, or enum expected error with exceedingly simple tester class

Tags: java, class, enums, compiler-errors

I'm having trouble finding out the reason im getting the expected class error. I have a class declared that houses just one main method but even when I comment out everything but the brackets I still get the same error. I've been looking at the four brackets for a while now, and can't seem to figure out what the problem is. How can i tell if two java files are in the same "package?"

Also, it's pointing to after my last bracket for where it thinks the error is.

EDIT: I decided to just write more code and now I'm getting a not a statement error on line 17 of my code. the integer declaration. I'm very confused as to what's happening

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BugTester
{

public static void main (String[] args)
   {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int userMove;
char userDir;
Bug lady = new Bug(1,1,'E');
lady.draw();

lady.printCurrentPosition();

int continue=1;
while (continue ==1)
   {
System.out.println("Please enter new Direction"); 
userDir = (char) System.in.read();

System.out.println("Please enter Distance to be moved"); 
userMove = in.nextInt();

lady.turn(userDir);
lady.move(userMove);

System.out.println("Again(0 to stop)?"); 
continue = in.nextInt();


   }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably have an invalid invisible char at the end of file. You can go to the end with the cursor and then delete all chars after the last bracket. It has helped for me.

**EDIT**

Remark about your new code:

The word "continue" is a  keyword in Java, you cannot use it as variable name.

Comment: Is it possible my IDE is.. broken? Because now I'm getting a "not a statement" error when I try and make an integer.


Ill try and edit the post to show you